# Run batch file and delete current parent directory

Tags: batch-file, rmdir

Here is my current set up.

```
C:\user\Desktop\folder
C:\user\Desktop\folder\run.bat
```

Because I wasn't able to use `rmdir` to delete the parent `folder` I tried making a `helper.bat` file that was added to the Desktop that would ideally delete the `folder` and delete itself after running. But I guess the process is still running, so it will only delete the contents of `folder` but not `folder` itself?

**run.bat:**

```
set HELPERFILE=helper.bat
cd %cd%
cd ..
echo echo Deleting the directory...>%HELPERFILE%
echo pause>>%HELPERFILE%
echo rmdir /s /q testfolder>>%HELPERFILE%
echo del %HELPERFILE%>>%HELPERFILE%
echo pause>>%HELPERFILE%
echo exit>>%HELPERFILE%
call "testing" /wait %HELPERFILE%
```

How can I delete everything after running `run.bat` including the parent directory it is contained within? I believe it has something to do with `call` and/or `start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to make sure that your batch file is no longer running **and** that nothing is *in* a folder being deleted (that is, nothing has a folder to be deleted as the current directory).

Given a structure

```
Z:\
Z:\Test
Z:\Test\Kill
Z:\Test\Kill\run.bat
```

the following *run.bat* will completely remove the *Kill* folder

```
REM Do Stuff
start rmdir Z:\test\kill /s /q
```

If you run the batch file from a command window, make sure you are *not* in the *Kill* folder, e.g.

> Z:\Test> Kill\run.tab

Answer (score 1):

Here you go this should work for you..DP ;-)

```
@echo off

:: SELF DESTRUCT CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY (Files, Sub directories and Root Parent Directory)
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe>nul 2>&1
set _sd=%~dp0
cd /d c:\
start cmd /c rd/s/q "%_sd%">nul 2>&1&start explorer.exe>nul 2>&1
```